# VBA passing date in stored procedure problems

Tags: sql, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I'm having difficulty passing a Date value to a datetime value using a SQL Stored Procedure. The `@DateTime` parameter is in datetime format in MyDb in a Microsoft SQL Server. When I run the below subroutine, I get an error: `Parameter type not supported.` I believe the error has to do with with the `adDBTimeStamp` parameter type. Any idea how to resolve this problem?

```
Public Sub AddDateTime

Dim DateTime as Date
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim param as ADODB.Parameter
Dim sConnString As String

/*Create the connection string*/

DateTime = Now()

sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=TheServer3;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = sConnString
cmd.CommandText = "usp_AddNewDateTime"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@DateTime", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , DateTime)
cmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rs = cmd.Execute

/*Clean up*/

Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: confirm adDBTimeStamp = 135

Answer (score 1):

Since you are providing a `Date` value, just use `adDBDate`:

```
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@DateTime", adDBDate, adParamInput, , DateTime)
```

Comment: I still get `Parameter type not supported.` and I'm directed to: `Set rs = cmd.Execute`

Comment: What's odd is that if I replace `DateTime` variable with 41765 (the date today), there are no errors.

Comment: But if I replace `DateTime` with `Format(DateTime, "General Number")`, I get the error again.

Comment: @bfs1990 "adDBDate" is not supported by SQL server, you have to use "adDBTimeStamp"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214459/en

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution -- The DateTime variable has to be converted to a Double: `CDbl(DateTime)`